# What is the difference between "blame someone for doing something" and "blame someone for having done something"?

Tags: grammar, perfect-aspect

Could you tell me what is the difference in meaning between *blame someone for doing something* and *blame someone for having done something*? For example:

> Kate **blames** Jack for **ruining** the cake.
>
> Kate **blames** Jack **for having ruined** the cake.

Comment: What's the context? What did Jack do to ruin the cake? Did he trip and accidentally drop the cake onto the floor or did he switch the sugar with the salt before someone made the cake?  Is Kate referring to "now" "this morning" or a week ago?

Comment: One way of interpreting the two uses: 1. *She blames him* **for breaking her heart** her heart is now broken. 2. *She blames him **for having broken her heart*** . Perhaps her heart is no longer in acute pain, time has begun its healing process.

Comment: What do *you* think is the difference?

Comment: What @Mari-LouA said. Another way of looking at it... 3. *I'm coughing, and I blame you for **smoking** in my house* would be a far more likely verb choice if the person I'm blaming is puffing away ***while I'm blaming him for doing so***. Whereas 4. *I'm coughing, and I blame you for **having smoked** in my house* quite explicitly blames the addressee for what he *did*, not necessarily what he's *doing*. But in many other contexts they're equivalent and interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - (1) Kate **blames** Jack for **ruining** the cake.
> - (2) Kate **blames** Jack **for having ruined** the cake.

In th4e absence of context, (1) and (2) have much the same meaning.  The longer ago the event is, the more likely it is that a native speaker will use (2) instead of (1).  But (1) could still be used even if the event was decades ago. The use of (2) emphasizes the distance in time, and the completion of the event. It is more likely to be used when the problem has since been fixed oe dealt with, as the 'having broken her heart" example in a comment by Fumblefingers suggests. The form (1) emphasizes the immediacy (emotional if not temporal) of the event. Beyond tht it is a mater od style, unless additional context makes the difference more important.